# using paypal DoDirectPayment method via HttpWebResponse, Do I need IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I received 
"the request was aborted could not create ssl/tls secure channel. paypal sandbox"

This error occurs on localhost.

But in paypal email they said I do not need to change IPN Verification Postback to HTTPS

Comment: Did the DoDirectPayment request complete successfully?  That's typically where you'd see errors about SSL/TLS, but then that call would never actually make it to PayPal so you'd get a blank response back (other than an HTTP error)

Comment: on my live server DoDirectPayment request complete successfully, but not on localhost. 
On live server i use paypal live payment link nad on localhost i use sandbox

Comment: You need to make sure your HTTP requests are happening over the TLS 1.2 protocol instead of SSLv3.  If it's not running over TLS 1.2 then the sandbox won't accept the API request in the first place, so then no transaction will have occurred and no IPN would ever be triggered at all.